# Weird issue when making an array of random ints in C

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-definition

I am currently learning C and I need to write a function to create an array of random integers. I've hit a problem where after creating I try to print and it the first 8 numbers correctly but the rest don't.

```
int* create(int n) {
    int* array = malloc(n);
    if (!array) return NULL;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        printf("num: %i\n", array[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", array[i]);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Here is my output for this:

```
num: 39
num: 2
num: 15
num: 74
num: 80
num: 29
num: 14
num: 16
num: 8
num: 11
num: 2
39
2
15
74
80
29
14
16
973747761
909588276
2614
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues with your code:
`malloc` expects a `size_t`, you are directly giving an `int`. So you should technically do:

```
    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

This basically says that allocate `n` blocks of `sizeof(int)` bytes each.
What you are doing is allocating `n` bytes of data. The program is not guaranteed to run always and you are running out of bounds. If you were lucky you would get a `Segmentation Fault` in one of the runs.

Comment: Giving an `int` argument for `malloc` is not inherently a problem. The argument will be automatically converted. It it overflowed the `int` range, that would be a problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ahh yes. The compiler will just implicitly typecast `int` to `size_t`. But be careful with negative `int` (eg: `malloc(-1)` will cause integer overflow and allocate almost all memory on OSes with very basic memory allocators).

Answer (score 4):

This memory allocation

```
int* array = malloc(n);
```

allocates not enough memory for an array with `n` elements of the type `int`, You have to write

```
int* array = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );
```

Also the parameter should have unsigned integer type. Otherwise the user can pass a negative integer that will result in undefined behavior.

It is better to declare the parameter as having the type `size_t`. It is the type of the parameter of the function `malloc`.

And the function should do one thing: allocate and initialize an array. It is the caller of the function that will decide whether to output the array provided that the function did not return a null pointer.

So the function can look like

```
int * create( size_t n ) 
{
    const int MAX_VALUE = 100;

    int *array = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( array != NULL )
    { 
        srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )  
        {
            array[i] = rand() % MAX_VALUE + 1;
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int * create( size_t n ) 
{
    const int MAX_VALUE = 100;

    int *array = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( array != NULL )
    { 
        srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )  
        {
            array[i] = rand() % MAX_VALUE + 1;
        }
    }

    return array;
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    printf( "Enter the size of an array: " );
    
    scanf( "%zu", &n );
    
    int *array = create( n );
    
    if ( array != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", array[i] );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    free( array );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the size of an array: 10
75 36 30 75 53 49 42 52 61 9
```

Though it is better to declare the function such a way that the user can determine the maximum value himself. That is the function can look like

```
int * create( size_t n, int max_value ) 
{
    int *array = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( array != NULL )
    { 
        srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )  
        {
            array[i] = rand() % max_value + 1;
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't allocating enough space. `malloc(n)` allocates `n` bytes. You need space for `n` ints! Use `malloc(n * sizeof(int))`, or more preferably: `malloc(n * sizeof(*array))` (so you don't need to repeat the type) instead.